# Highcharts setting weird column spacing with monthly timeseries

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to build a highcharts column chart showing monthly data. This is what I get (note the irregular separation between columns):

[image: First Chart]

An here's the way I'm building the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/Lae2zg11/2/

I thought it might be a problem with the timestamp timezone (`1451602800000`, for example, is `31/12/2015 23:00:00` in GMT, but `01/01/2016 00:00:00` in my timezone, and that's the datetime I need.

So I updated the chart data to "translate" my datetimes to GMT, but I get pretty much the same result:

[image]

And the related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lae2zg11/3/

So apparently it has nothing to do with the datetime format itself. How can I get evenly separated columns, and columns with the same width?

Comment: Well your x-values are not evenly spaced, so the columns only represent the differences in your datetime-value gaps. The width of the columns are the same.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured out. The question is how can I force the columns to be evenly spaced. A monthly aggregated timeseries should look regular, despite the (obvious) fact that each month has a different number of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to switch to Highstock you can use their `ordinal` feature:

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them.

You'd have to use the Highstock script instead:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

Then create your standard chart (Highcharts style) with an ordinal x-axis:

```
$('#container').highcharts('Chart', {
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: true,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/Lae2zg11/4/) of your chart with these modifications.